# ¿variable no esta definida?

Tags: javascript

declaro un array en javascript a partir de otro array y me dice que la variable esta indefinida esto lo trato de usar para ordenar los valores en javascript sin desordenar la matriz

```js
let piloto1 = [9]
piloto1[0] = "JOSE   " ;
piloto1[1] = 11042019 ;
piloto1[2] = 14042019 ;
piloto1[3] = 19042019 ;
piloto1[4] = 24052019 ;
piloto1[5] = 04062019 ;
piloto1[6] = 09072019 ;
piloto1[7] = 18072019 ;
piloto1[8] = 22072019 ;
;
let racer = [8]
racer[0] = piloto1[1];
racer[1] = piloto1[2];
racer[2] = piloto1[3];
racer[3] = piloto1[4];
racer[4] = piloto1[5];
racer[5] = piloto1[6];
racer[6] = piloto1[7];
racer[7] = piloto1[8];
;
racer.sort(ordenar);
document.write(racer);


function ordenar(a,b) {
  return a-b;
}
```

Comment: He metido tu código en un snippet para que veas que funciona. (aun así tienes un par de `;` descolocados). Supongo que tu problema es lanzar varias veces el mismo código, por lo que si declarar una variable la primera vez te funciona y la segunda vez la tienes que "pisar" y no volverla a declarar. `let piloto1 = [9]` y la segunda vez -> `piloto1 = [9] //piloto1 ya existe`

Comment: Tengo tan interiorizado lo de definir el tamaño del array en Java que he pasado por alto el detalle que comenta @Mauricio-Contreras que estas intentado definir el tamaño del array. En JS no es necesario, por lo que el comentario que he puesto antes sería: `let piloto1 = []` y la segunda vez -> `piloto1 = [] //piloto1 ya existe` o en caso que quieras definir el tamaño puedes utilizar `let piloto1 = new Array(9)` y la segunda vez -> `piloto1 = new Array(9)`

Answer (score 1):

Tienes algunos detalles conceptuales en tu pregunta, trataré de explicarlos en mi respuesta.

**Arrays en JavaScript**

Una de las cosas que ve en tu pregunta es lo siguiente:

> declaro un array en javascript ...

Y luego veo que en tu código pones:

```
let piloto1 = [9]
piloto1[0] = "JOSE   " ;
piloto1[1] = 11042019 ;
piloto1[2] = 14042019 ;
piloto1[3] = 19042019 ;
piloto1[4] = 24052019 ;
piloto1[5] = 04062019 ;
piloto1[6] = 09072019 ;
piloto1[7] = 18072019 ;
piloto1[8] = 22072019 ;
;
```

Y entiendo que tu concepto de declarar un `Array` es darle la dimensión al mismo, porque esta primera declaración no tiene otro sentido:

```
let piloto1 = [9]
```

Tal vez vienes de otros lenguajes como C, C++, Java, etc., en los cuales al declarar un `array` hay que indicar el tamaño del mismo.

Por ejemplo en [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) se puede usar:

```java
int[] piloto1 = new int[9];
```

Pero en Javascript, un lenguaje no tipado, la declaración de un `Array` se puede hacer de las siguientes maneras:

```js
let piloto1 = []; // <- se incializa sin elementos
console.log(`piloto1.length: ${piloto1.length}`); // 0

let piloto2 = [9]; // <- se inicializa con 1 elemento cuyo valor es 9
console.log(`piloto2.length: ${piloto2.length}`); // 1

let piloto3 = new Array(9); // <- se inicializa usando el constructor del objeto global, pasando un solo argumento que indica la dimensión del array
console.log(`piloto3.length: ${piloto3.length}`); // 9

let piloto4 = new Array(1,2,3); // <- se inicializa usando el constructor del objeto global, se pasan los elementos del array separados por coma
console.log(`piloto4.length: ${piloto4.length}`); // 3
```

Lo mismo aplica para el segundo `array` que estás creando.

**Copiar elementos de un Array a otro Array en Javascript**

Otra de las cosas que me parece que puedes mejorar en tu código es la forma en la que copias los elementos de tu `array` llamado `piloto1` en el `array` llamado `racer`.

Para no hacer esto a mano, dispones de algunos métodos, veamos un ejemplo muy simple usando un bucle `for` y el método [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push):

```js
// iniciamos un array vacío
let piloto1 = [];
// ahora llenamos el array
piloto1[0] = "JOSE   " ;
piloto1[1] = 11042019 ;
piloto1[2] = 14042019 ;
piloto1[3] = 19042019 ;
piloto1[4] = 24052019 ;
piloto1[5] = 04062019 ;
piloto1[6] = 09072019 ;
piloto1[7] = 18072019 ;
piloto1[8] = 22072019 ;

// iniciamos otro array vacío
let racer = []
// ahora usamos un bucle for y llenamos a partir del primer array
for(let i = 1; i < piloto1.length; i++) {
  //inciamos el bucle en 1 y no en 0 (porque el primer elmento del array piloto1 no nos interesa)
  racer.push(piloto1[i]); // usamos push
}

//verificamos el tamaño del array
console.log(racer.length) // 8
```

Con esto espero que te quede un poco más claro la forma en la que se declaran `Array` en Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

el problema esta en `let`, deberías de utilizar `var`.

Las variables `let` tienen por alcance el bloque en el que han definido y **en el nivel superior de un programa, no crear una propiedad en el `objeto global`**

Más información en: [Javascript | MDN -> Let](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let#Reglas_de_alcance)

Comment: la cambie como dijiste pero sigue saliendo lo mismo

Comment: Acaba de copiar y pegar el código cambiando `let` por `var` y si que funciona. Tienes algo más en la etiqueta de `script`?